# Rescale number range which keeps orginal spacing

Tags: python

I have a number range as follows,

```
[0.31622776601683794, 0.26591479484724945, 0.24028114141347545, 0.22360679774997896, 
 0.21147425268811282, 0.20205155046766235, 0.19441308418139638, 0.1880301546543197, 
 0.18257418583505536, 0.17782794100389226]
```

I would like to rescale the number range so the first item is 1, the last item 0 with all other items maintaing there spacing relative to the original list.

Also I need all the values in the list to add up to 1 in the final list. Excluding the first item.

I'm absolutely rubbish at maths, so if anyone would know how do to this is python I would be very grateful ...

Comment: So what's the expected output for your example?

Comment: If the first item is 1 and you want sum of all items as 1 then you need `[1,0, 0, 0,..., 0] `.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary what about [1, -1, 1, 0 ... ]? ;)

Comment: OP: the numbers are known to be non-negative right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subtract the `last` from all, and divide all by the `first`.

```
emil ~ > python 
Python 2.7.1 (r271:86832, Aug  5 2011, 03:30:24) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2335.15.00)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> l = [0.31622776601683794, 0.26591479484724945, 0.24028114141347545, 0.22360679774997896, 
...  0.21147425268811282, 0.20205155046766235, 0.19441308418139638, 0.1880301546543197, 
...  0.18257418583505536, 0.17782794100389226]
>>> l
[0.31622776601683794, 0.26591479484724945, 0.24028114141347545, 0.22360679774997896, 0.21147425268811282, 0.20205155046766235, 0.19441308418139638, 0.1880301546543197, 0.18257418583505536, 0.17782794100389226]
>>> len(l)
10
>>> l1 = []
>>> l1[:] = [x - l[9] for x in l]
>>> l1
[0.13839982501294568, 0.08808685384335718, 0.06245320040958319, 0.0457788567460867, 0.03364631168422055, 0.024223609463770085, 0.01658514317750412, 0.010202213650427422, 0.004746244831163093, 0.0]
>>> l2 = []
>>> l2[:] = [x/l1[0] for x in l1]
>>> l2 
[1.0, 0.6364665116817719, 0.4512520185899182, 0.33077250453029566, 0.2431094958470745, 0.175026301236322, 0.11983500106270202, 0.0737155097520761, 0.03429371988526097, 0.0]
```

And to **normalize** (sum = 1) :

```
>>> l3 = []
>>> l3[:] = [x/sum(l2) for x in l2]
>>> l3
[0.3263205883093977, 0.20769212653122596, 0.14725282418206537, 0.107937878274899, 0.07933163370841843, 0.05711468558905446, 0.03910462804683822, 0.024054888509824617, 0.01119074684827605, 0.0]
```

However you can't meet the conditions you asked for unless the *sum of the numbers between the first and last is 0*, so for your sample data it is impossible.

Answer (score 2):

You ask for something that is impossible.

If the minimal number is 0 and the max is 1, then the sum will be greater than 1 (unless all the numbers are equal except the highest).
Also, you if want to maintain the absolute distances between the numbers, you can set either the min or the max, not both.

However, here is some code that may help. If you have a numpy array `a`:

```
a-=np.min(a)
```

will set the minimum to be 0.

And:

```
a/=np.max(a)
```

will set the maximum to 1.

And:

```
a/=np.sum(a)
```

will set the sum to 1.

Comment: @arshajii `a/=np.sum(a)` will give a sum of exactly 1.

Comment: @arshajii thanks, I now addressed the odd case in my answer.